# Sprout Email conflicts with Craft Contact Form

Tags: plugin-sproutforms, plugin-contactform

I have the latest versions of Craft CMS, Sprout Email and Craft Contact plugins. Sprout behaves fine with some notifications I have set up. However, if I submit a contact form it throws a PHP error - `mb_convert_case() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

If I disable Sprout, then Contact Form works fine.

Looking at the logs, I see that submitting the form triggers a 'When an entry is saved' event and Sprout starts looking at whether it is something it should handle and then chokes when trying to parse it as an entry.

I finally got things to work by disabling the "Enable Sent Email tracking" feature in Sprout Email, but I would prefer not to have to do that.

Has anyone encountered anything like this or have any thoughts on this? Thanks for any input!

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace for that error?  It sounds like a Sprout bug, but can't say for sure without seeing.

Comment: This is currently a bug in Sprout Email. We'll have a fix out next release. I've made a note to update this thread when we do.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved in [Sprout Email 3](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/email).

Be sure to read the upgrade notes. This is a major release and some scenarios may require a few manual steps to get updated.