# Craft CMS Content has Disappeared?

Tags: error-message, error, content

My content within all of my pages has disappeared.  The website is only displaying the header and footer on each page. When I try to restore the internal page to it's previous version to get the content back I get this error: "Internal Server Error: mb_convert_case() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given".  I also cannot add anything to my pages other than Assets.  When can I do to get the content back?  Any ideas on how to fix the Error I'm getting?  Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Any changes in the codebase before the error occurred? Any craft (or other) updates?

Comment: possible solution here? https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/22189/sprout-email-conflicts-with-craft-contact-form

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a page using the neo blocks for content. https://github.com/spicywebau/craft-neo

Someone had modified the field for that page from "Neo" to "Asset", the exact same problem you had. The version history was trying to display historic content for Neo blocks in an in compatible field type, so it crashed.

Resolution was to go back to the field for that page back to "Neo" and then version history worked once again and I could restore my page.

As a note, there is a warning on the fields editor that modifying the type of field will reset your page content!